# Project Orion pusher plate computer modeling

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics, plasma-physics, nuclear-engineering

Linked from the space.stackexchange forum:
https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/orion-project-npp-pusher-plate-computer-models-and-survivability

Project Orion is discussed as if it is a certainty that it would have worked. I am skeptical. Has anyone ever done a high resolution computer model of the plasma impacting the pusher plate?

Comment: Unobtanium was a commonly used material in the 1950s and 1960s. Its use in engineering designs has fallen slightly out of favor as it is expensive and usually outright impossible to obtain.

Comment: They planned to use steel, tapered from 6" thick at the edge to much thicker in the middle, so the mass profile matched the impulse profile of the impacting plasma. A thin coating of graphite-rich oil would be sprayed over the plate between pulses, which would vaporize and protect the plate from erosion. That was as far as theory took them. They would need to do physical testing to verify that it would hold up to multiple blasts. Much later we developed computer codes, initially for nuclear bomb design, that could answer this. Has anyone ever used them on this problem?

Comment: "In theory there is no difference between theory and practice, in practice there is." - Yoggi Berra, who never really said this.

Comment: The assertion that modern computer codes could answer this is questionable at best. An answer actually requires a succession of simulations: bomb output, rad transport to pusher, debris transport to pusher, rad transport & energy deposition in pusher, thermomechanical response to energy deposition, vaporization/blowoff, thermomechanical response to vaporization/blowoff, thermomechanical response to debris, etc, etc. This is not a problem you could just plug into a code existing today for a virtual flight test; and even if you could, the result would be dubious until validated.